# How does the ForceMove protocol handle timed dispute periods?

Tags: state-channels, timers, layer-2

The main idea behind the [ForceMove](https://github.com/magmo/force-move-protocol)
protocol is that, in a state channel between predefined participants running turn-based applications, lets say 2 for this example (Alice and Bob), if it is Bob's turn to play and he becomes non-responsive, Alice can issue a challenge and "force his move". Essentially, the creation of a challenge gives Bob a "predefined time window" to respond, otherwise the game terminates in the last valid state.

It is unclear to me after reading the related publication how the countdown for the response window is implemented, since timers and time are famously a sensitive issue on the blockchain. If someone that has looked into this further (or read and understood the paper more than I did) could point out how they execute a countdown securely, it would be very appreciated, thank you.